# How can i get infinite number of item for my structure

Tags: java, android, list, android-listview

```
  Article article = null;
  Article article2 = null;
  Article article3 = null;
  if (position == 0)
  {
  article = getItem(0);
  article2 = getItem(1);
  article3 = getItem(2);
  }
  else if (position == 1)
  {
  article = getItem(3);
  article2 = getItem(4);
  article3 = getItem(5);
  }
  else if (position == 2)
  {
      article = getItem(6);
      article2 = getItem(7);
      article3 = getItem(8);
  }
```

I need to get  my item list like this, but i can't do that until 90th item(position).
How can i write these codes for infinite times.

Comment: ArticleX = getItem(position*3 + X)

Comment: What do you use as a container of your data? An ArrayList?

Comment: @JejeDoudou Yes,Something like arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to get my item list like this, but i can't do that until 90th
>   item(position). How can i write these codes for infinite times.

You can do it in that way:

```
article = getItem((position * 3));
article2 = getItem((position * 3) + 1);
article3 = getItem((position * 3) + 2);
```

This is simple solution and will make a trick for you.